how to combine cpg information on both strands in analysis?
I’m trying to understand how bioinformatics tools import BS files, especially in terms of merging methylation data from the forward and reverse strands. How is this information represented in the final output? For instance, what happens when the CpG sites are symmetric, when data is available from only one strand, or when the two strands have differing methylation statuses? Thank you:).


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What are BS files? Do you have any example files (e.g. the first few lines of a file)?

Hi, i have added an example pic :).
